# flex get contents of arraycollection as Date

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder, flexbuilder

I use httpService to load data from mysql database.
I put event.result on arraycollection.
I need to convert one field to AS3 Date format, I can use  "for each" too do that but as my arraycollection is big, it's take a long time.
Do you a solution to accelerate this conversion.

The field I like to convert is like that : "2012-03-12 14:30:00"

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why do you need it converted?

Comment: Why don't you convert it on the webservice or in the MySQL query?

Comment: I need to convert to use with a calendar component. In this component event start must be a Date. As my result is object format, is event.result.dateField is on Date format?

Comment: @Flex60460 you might want to show some of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the [DateFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html) class?

There is a function stringToDate which takes String argument and returns Date object. Pay attention formatString property.

Best and correct way would be return date objects from backend.